# How is used requirejs

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

Sorry for the question, but I'm new in js
How should I use require, I have try differents ways, nothing

Try like this

```
<script src="Scripts/js/require.js"></script>
```

Like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
```

```
var jsonDat = require('./file.json');
console.log(jsonDat); //undefined
let jsonDat = require('./file.json');
console.log(jsonDat); //undefined
```

Always the same result in the console: 
undefined

I see example like this one: https://blog.codingblocks.com/2018/reading-json-files-in-nodejs-require-vs-fs-readfile/
looks easy but it's not working
I'm running a HTTP server like this

```
npx http-server -c-1
```

Could someone post a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Both ways of including RequireJS in the browser are fine.

But the article you gave is about reading JSON file in the NodeJS, not in the browser. These are different environments.

NodeJS and RequireJS are defining function `define()` but they are working differently.

In NodeJS, it work synchronously, so when you require a file, script execution stops, the file is loaded and returned:

```js
var json = require('./another');
console.log(js); // things defined in another.js
```

But, in the RequireJS module as loaded asynchronously, so you need to pass callback which will be executed when file is loaded, it is injected to your callback:

```js
require(['./another'], function (another) { // 
  console.log(another); // things defined in another.js
}];
```

But if you want to require a json file via RequireJS you need to have a plugin for that (https://github.com/requirejs/text):

```js
require(['text!./file.json'], function (json) {
  console.log(json); // content of json file
});
```

Hope that helps